# Permutation with local maxima

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, permutations, expected-value

I'm trying solve this problem:

*Permutation of numbers $1$ to $n$ has a local maximum on $j^{th}$ position if number on $j^{th}$ position is bigger than both its neighbours. For first and last number of a permutation, local maximum exists if that number is bigger than its only neighbour. Knowing that every of $n!$ permutations is equally expected, calculate expected number of local maxima.*

I tried defining $X$ (variable) with $X_i$ equal to number of local maxima on $i^{th}$ position, but couldn't continue past that.

Comment: Putnam 2006-A4 See http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2006s.pdf

Comment: Hint: instead of counting by permutations (add the number of local maxima for each permutations), count by positions (add the number of permutations that have a local maximum at a specific position).

Comment: @CatalinZara The link that you provided answered my question and I'm very thankful for that. If you want you can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm happy that you found an answer to your question, but I don't think providing a link really qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @CatalinZara You can always rewrite the answer from the link.